# how to set two os.environ in one single flask project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

i have a project in gogole cloud with `automl vision` , and another project in google  cloud `automl tables`, but i have two `os.environ`

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='path/to/my/fileVisionKey.json'
```

and

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='path/to/my/fileTablesKey.json'
```

for each project. Please can i gather them in one single `app.py` instead of separate them into different flask project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify these files separately when instantiating the the clients for these APIs, rather than using the environment variable.

```py
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl

vision_client = automl.AutoMlClient.from_service_account_json('path/to/my/fileVisionKey.json')
tables_client = automl.AutoMlClient.from_service_account_json('path/to/my/fileTablesKey.json')
```